# Need source of a quote

Tags: sources-mekorot, olam-haba-world-to-come, quotations

"In this world, we suffer because we are Jewish.  In the World to Come, we will suffer because we are not Jewish enough."

Comment: Interesting. Where'd you hear/read it?

Comment: In a French book, with no source other than "Judaism says".

Comment: What book is this?

Comment: It'll come back to me, I hope.

Comment: If you have the original French, a google search might provide other instances (and one might have a source)

Comment: @rosends -- Hey, that was a good idea!  This site says it's a Judeo-Spanish saying, in Ladino.  My father would have loved it.  (But even so, it may have a source.)

https://diariojudio.com/idioma/frances/proverbes-judeo-espagnols/179317/
Le sort malheureux des Juifs au cours de l'histoire a engendré ce proverbe:
3) En este mundo sufrimos, porke semos djudyos, en el otro sufriremos porke no fuimos djudyos (" En ce monde nous souffrons parce que nous sommes juifs, dans l'autre nous souffrirons pour ne l'avoir pas été (sous-entendu, " assez ").

Comment: It's a good one, in the original as well as in translation. Many Judeo-Spanish proverbs have a source in sifrei kodesh ("He who prepares on Friday will eat on Shabbat", which is also a Gemarra, comes to mind) but some are just folk sayings. I have a feeling this one falls into the latter category.

Comment: ''In a French book, with no source other than "Judaism says". '' from Jacques Attali ?

Comment: @kouty -- Non !